# Jackson library ignoring properties

Tags: json, jackson

Jackson    @JsonIgnoreProperties    not ignoring possibleTargets  ,but  ignoring owner and lemf .How i can ignore lists.

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties( {"owner","lemf"," possibleTargets"} )
@Entity
public class Warrant extends Nameable {

    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    @OneToMany(mappedBy ="warrant",targetEntity = com.endersys.lims.model.Target.class)
    private List<Target> possibleTargets;
```

Output:

```
[{"status":"SCHEDULED","startDate":1320962400000,"endDate":1320962400000,"caseId":"1","possibleTargets":[],"name":"warrant_1","description":"decription","identity":"warrant_1","version":1,"systemId":1,"active":true}]
```

Comment: " possibleTargets" has a space on its start

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was also have problem lazyload because jackson was trying to serialize ignored fields.I have find a post  [related](http://kyrill007.livejournal.com/2577.html) to this.Using jackson 1.9 problem solved ,I use @JsonIgnore  but @JsonIgnoreProperties still not working on onetomany relations.

Comment: You could file a bug report in this case, if the other version you tried is 1.8 (earlier versions are not maintained any more)?

Comment: @StackMan  JsonIgnoreProperties   not working as expected i will  post a jira issue

Answer (score 0):

Use Jackson version 2.4 it works perfectly.

This is how you can implemented:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"id"})
```

In this [developerWork post](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-hangman-app/index.html) I found an example to implement Jackson v2.4 all the code and library is available.